# libclang returns too much info about function declarations

Tags: c++, clang, libclang

I have the following code that uses the clang-c API.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

CXChildVisitResult printVisitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data) 
{       
    CXCursor cursor1 = clang_getCursorReferenced(cursor);

    CXType type = clang_getCursorType(cursor1);
    CXCursorKind kind = clang_getCursorKind(cursor1);
    CXString str = clang_getTypeSpelling(type);
    CXString str1 = clang_getCursorSpelling(cursor1);
    std::string cstr = clang_getCString(str);
    std::string cstr1 = clang_getCString(str1);

    if(type.kind != 0 && kind == CXCursorKind::CXCursor_FunctionDecl)
    {
        std::cout << "Declaration!\n" << "type is: " << cstr << std::endl;
        std::cout << "name is: " << cstr1 << std::endl;
    }

    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
 CXIndex index = clang_createIndex (
         false, // excludeDeclarationFromPCH
         true   // displayDiagnostics
 );
 CXTranslationUnit unit = clang_parseTranslationUnit (
         index,                           // CIdx
         "main1.cpp",                      // source_filename
         argv + 1 ,                        // command_line_args
         argc - 1 ,                        // num_command_line_args
         0,                                // unsave_files
         0,                                // num_unsaved_files
         CXTranslationUnit_None           // options
 );
 if (unit != 0 )
         std::cout << "Translation unit successfully created" << std::endl;
 else
         std::cout << "Translation unit was not created" << std::endl;

 CXCursor rootCursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(unit);

    clang_visitChildren(rootCursor, printVisitor, NULL);


 clang_disposeTranslationUnit(unit);
 clang_disposeIndex(index);
}
```

This code parses the following.

```
double getSum(double a, float b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    float b = 6;
    double c = a + b;
    return getSum(c, b);
}
```

When the program runs, I see the following.

```
    Translation unit successfully created
    Declaration!
    type is: double (double, float)
    name is: getSum
    Declaration!
    type is: int ()
    name is: main
    Declaration!
    type is: double (double, float)
    name is: getSum
    Declaration!
    type is: double (double, float)
    name is: getSum
    Declaration!
    type is: double (double, float)
    name is: getSum
    Declaration!
    type is: double (double, float)
    name is: getSum
```

Why do I get so much declarations of `getSum()`, when in the code I have a single declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `clang_getCursorReferenced`, you get the `CXCursor` which is referenced at the current location. For example, a function declaration references itself, and is referenced by the corresponding function call(s). In your example, you will thus get positive matches for every reference to a function declaration (either a function declaration itself or a function call).

Now the other thing is that each `CXCursor` represents a part of the AST, either a leaf or a more complex part with subparts. For example, while traversing the AST, you'll find in turn the following cursors:

- `return getSum (c, b)`
- `getSum (c, b)`
- `getSum`

All these cursors reference the `getSum` function declaration, and my guess is that these are the cursors which trigger multiple references to `getSum`.

You can check which part of the source code corresponds to the current cursor by calling [`clang_getCursorExtent`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__SOURCE.html#ga79f6544534ab73c78a8494c4c0bc2840)

Answer (score 3):

I've never used clang, but based on [the documentation of CXCursor](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/structCXCursor.html) it seems that the `CXCursorKind` will always be `Declaration` whenever the cursor is *somewhere* in a function (`main` may get special treatment I suppose). This may explain why you have multiple reports of a declaration of `Sum`.

I base my conjecture on the definition of `CXCursorKind`, found [here](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/Index_8h_source.html):

```
enum CXCursorKind {
  /* Declarations */
  /**
   * \brief A declaration whose specific kind is not exposed via this
   * interface.
   *
   * Unexposed declarations have the same operations as any other kind
   * of declaration; one can extract their location information,
   * spelling, find their definitions, etc. However, the specific kind
   * of the declaration is not reported.
   */
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer kicked to me to understand that the reason is using clang_getCursorReferenced; I don't know why, but when using simple CXCursor it's allright:) Thanks!